# Store Arabic text in mysql database using php

Tags: php, mysql, utf-8, character-encoding, mysqli

I am trying to store some Arabic data in a mysql database 
I have set the html document charset to be 'utf8'

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
```

MySQL charset is set to: UTF-8 Unicode (utf8)

MySQL connection collation is set to: utf8_general_ci

Database and table collations are set to: utf8_general_ci

In addition in my php code I used the `$mysqli->set_charset("utf8")` function to ensure that the charset is set to be ut8 but nothing is actually working , I am posting my data to the php script using html form where the enctype is : `enctype="multipart/form-data"` because in this form I also upload an image

The weird thing is that when I write my query directly in mysql the Arabic characters are stored properly with no problem , but when I use a php query to store the data all the characters are stored in a wrong charset encoding

Any suggestions ?

Comment: @VahidHallaji actually it works ! thank you so much , I tried the 
$mysqli->set_charset("utf8") and then I tried your solution , thank you

Answer (score 3):

Weird, It should work!

Try adding these lines after a successful connection to the database:

```
$mysqli->query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");
$mysqli->query("SET CHARACTER SET utf8");
```

For example:

```
$mysqli = @new mysqli('DB_HOST', 'DB_USER', 'DB_PASS', 'DB_NAME');

if($mysqli->connect_errno) die('Connection Error!');
else{
    $mysqli->query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");
    $mysqli->query("SET CHARACTER SET utf8");
}
```

And include these META tags in the head section of your php page:

```
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
```

Answer (score 0):

Browsers will ignore the `<meta http-equiv ...>` tag if there is a http header present. Try putting this at the top of your php page:

```
header("Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8");
```

Answer (score 0):

save this file in ur website, htdocs folder as "dbh.php, then in include it at the top of your index page by typing `<?php include 'dbh.php';?>` and you u are ready to go.

```
<?php

$conn = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "database name");

if(!$conn){
    die("connection failed: ".mysqli_connect_error());
}else{
    $conn->query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");
    $conn->query("SET CHARACTER SET utf8");

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You may try this. It should work

```
<?php

$conn = mysqli_connect(<host>, <user name>, <password>, <database name>);

if(!$conn){
    die("could not connect: ".mysqli_connect_error());
}else{
    mysqli_query("SET character_set_results = 'utf8', character_set_client = 'utf8', character_set_connection = 'utf8', character_set_database = 'utf8', character_set_server = 'utf8'", $conn);
}
?>
```